# mvn deploy issue

Tags: maven, maven-2, nexus

I am using maven 3.0.3 with nexus & jenkins

### pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement> 
         <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
                               <url>http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8383/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>

         <!-- Publish the versioned releases here -->
         <snapshotRepository>
          <id>releases</id>
          <name>nexus</name>
          <url>http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8383/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
         </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

### settings.xml

```
<servers>
<server>
<username>admin</username>
<password>bala</password>
<id>releases</id>
</server>
</servers>
```

When I do mvn deploy

I get the following error. Would like to know where I missed and what have I missed?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy
> (default-deploy) on project mdaq: Deployment failed: repository
> element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement
> element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter ->
> [Help 1]

-------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you try to use different id for repository and snapshotRepository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven deployment issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427952/maven-deployment-issue)

Answer (score 1):

The `<id>` of your snapshot repository is the same as your releases repository.  Name them differently, and then put in two server definitions in your settings.xml file.  Also give the releases repository a `<name>`.  Like this:

```
<distributionManagement> 
         <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>nexus releases</name>
            <url>http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8383/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>

         <!-- Publish the versioned releases here -->
         <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>nexus snapshots</name>
            <url>http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8383/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
         </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
```

### settings.xml

```
<servers>
<server>
<id>releases</id>
<username>admin</username>
<password>bala</password>
</server>
<server>
<id>snapshots</id>
<username>admin</username>
<password>bala</password>
</server>
</servers>
```

Comment: No, mine works with the same <id>. I dont think this is the cause of the problem.